# Converting a SVN project containing tags to Mercurial

Tags: svn, mercurial

I am attempting to use the `hg convert` Mercurial command against an SVN repository that has a trunk and some tags (but no branches.)  The SVN folder layout looks like this:

```
Foo
  tags
    1.00a
    1.00b-test
  trunk
```

Although the import succeeds, it would appear I am only gettting the trunk and the tags are nowhere to be seen in the Hg repository.  Issuing `hg tags` or `hg branches` doesn't show them.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explictly passing in the directory containing the tags when running `hg convert`:

```
--config convert.svn.tags=tags            (directory name)
    specify the directory containing tags
```

from `hg help convert`.  If that doesn't do it, what's the exact covert command line you're using?  Is there anything in the .hgtags file after you run?

Comment: Specifying the tags folder name makes no difference.  The command line I'm using is `hg convert \path\to\svn\project`.  There is no .hgtags file created.

Comment: Try running "hg convert --debug \path\to\svn\project" and keep a log file of everything that is displayed. Then you should post the trace file to mercurial-devel@selenic.com and see if this is a bug in the *convert* extension when running under Windows.